# How to use convert bit column to string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit

I using `concat_ws` to concat multipul colums in MSSQL:

```
SELECT 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    CONCAT_WS(', ', last_name, first_name) tags
FROM 
    customers
```

I also have `is_male` column which is a `bit` (boolean) and I want to add it to `concat_ws`.

The problem is I got the value 0 or 1 without any indication about "what is this value".

I mean, how to using `concat_ws` to get the boolean if it exist? something like that:

```
tags
John Wick male
```

I was try to do those without success:

```
select concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, if is_male, 'male', '') as tags, *

select concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, concat(if is_male, 'male', '')) as tags, *

select concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, concat(if is_male = 1, 'male', '')) as tags, *
```

What else can I do?

Comment: use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expression . `case when is_male = 1 then 'male' else 'female' end`

Comment: If `IIF` (which is an inclined `CASE` expression)

Comment: Bit is not boolean - it is a numeric datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

```
select concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, 
                                  IIF(is_male = 1, 'male', 'female')) as tags
```

or with [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

```
select concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, 
                                  case when is_male = 1 then 'male' else 'female' end) as tags
```